# Running a Java Web Start application without Java Web Start

Tags: java, jar, classpath, java-web-start

I want to run a fat client delivered as a Java web start application without Java web start. I launched it via javaws and managed to get all the jar files mentioned in the JNLP file from the cache after they were downloaded.

I tried running the jar file that contains the main class according to the JNLP file, but I get the 'Could not find or load main class' error. Were I just trying to run a class I'd set the classpath accordingly, but since I'm running a jar file with java -jar, as far as I know the classpath settings will be ignored anyway. Now I'm not sure what to do, does anybody know how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this myself now, turns out it is stupidly simple: Get all the jar files, unzip them to get the content, merge all the content (best done with rsync), create a new MANIFEST.MF file that contains the main class to be loaded and the merged hashes for all existing files from all MANIFEST.MF files, zip again to create a jar. That's it.